# asp.net mvc3 razor Model validations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I had an combobox which was filled with various "countries". I had an textbox for "phone"     my problem is when we select the country as "United States" in combobox the phone number should be "10" digits. And if the country is other than "United States" the phone number could be anynumber of digits but less than "20". How can do  cleint side validations in asp.net mvc3 razor. Where i had to write any custom validator. Can any one please help me to find the solution.

Comment: Do you have thing called google?

Comment: Yes i had google but i could not find how to vary validation based on the combobox value.If you had thing called google please post the link You find which satisfy my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

these blog posts may help you

[**Complete guide to validation in MVC part 1**](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1)

[**The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2**](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)